# What is the origin of `%i` notation?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Ruby has classically supported the following literals:

```
%q[quack quack] #=> "quack quack"
%r[quack quack] #=> /quack quack/
%w[quack quack] #=> ["quack", "quack"]
%x[echo quack quack] #=> "quack quack\n"
```

My understanding of the origin of those are as follows:

- `%q[]` is for **q**uotes
- `%r[]` is for **r**egex
- `%w[]` is for **w**ords
- `%x[]` is for e**x**ecute

Ruby 2.0 introduced the `%i` notation:

```
%i[quack quack] #=> [:quack, :quack]
```

Why `i`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably a reference to the [`String#intern` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-intern) used to get a symbol from a string.

```
"foo".intern #=> :foo
```

Comment: Found that originally the idea was to use `%s`, but as it already existed for a single symbol (not an array), so here Aaron Patterson suggested to use `%i` exactly standing for `intern`: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4985#note-6